# Raycasting after dynamically changing Mesh in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, raycasting

I have a mesh cloned from another mesh. But after cloning, I translate and rotate it. And do a ray-casting a point to it but it is not working as expected. It is keep intersecting with the original position before translation and rotation. Sample code is as below

```
const raycaster = THREE.Raycaster()
const proposedModel = model.clone()
proposedModel.translateX(1)
proposedModel.translateY(1)
proposedModel.translateZ(1)
const q = new THREE.Quaternion(
    -0.847,
    -0.002,
    -0.505,
     0.168
)
proposedModel.applyQuaternion(q)

const point = new THREE.Vector3(1,1,1)
raycaster.set(point, new THREE.Vector3(1,1,1))
const intersects = raycaster.intersectObject(object) // It keep intersecting with original position
```

Glad if any help, Thanks!

Comment: After applying a quaternion, try to call `proposedModel.updateMatrixWorld()`.

Comment: It works! May I know why I need to call updateMatrixWorld() explicitly?

Comment: I think I found the answer: I founding the following in Three.js docs `When either the parent or the child object's transformation changes, you can request that the child object's matrixWorld be updated by calling updateMatrixWorld().`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call updateMatrixWorld() from the mesh after transformation will solve the problem. Credit to @prisoner849

`proposedModel.updateMatrixWorld()`

The reason is

> An object's matrix stores the object's transformation relative to the
>   object's parent; to get the object's transformation in world
>   coordinates, you must access the object's Object3D.matrixWorld.
>
> When either the parent or the child object's transformation changes,
>   you can request that the child object's matrixWorld be updated by
>   calling updateMatrixWorld().

Check detail here https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/introduction/Matrix-transformations

Comment: Actually, it's because `translateX` updates the `position` property. The `position` property doesn't get applied to the `matrixWorld` until either a render (with `autoUpdateMatrix` enabled), or you do it manually through `updateMatrixWorld`. Since you're not rendering, you need to do the latter, because the ray caster uses the world matrix to put the shape into the coordinate system the ray caster understands. Your answer is correct, it's just the details that are a little off. :)

Comment: @TheJim01Thanks. Good to know this