# Why does child object not move with parent in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

three.js r89

```
var A = new THREE.Object3D();
var B = new THREE.Object3D();
scene.add(A);
A.add(B);
A.position.set(0, 0, -2);

var bPos = B.getWorldPosition();
```

`bPos` is still `Vector3 {x: 0, y: 0, z: 0}`. Why? I thought it should be `Vector3 {x: 0, y: 0, z: -2}` (B moved with A).

Proof:
[image: proof]

Comment: Right after `A.position.set(0, 0, -2);`, try `A.updateMatrixWorld();`

Comment: That works, thanks! @prisoner849

Comment: I thought threejs will do that internally. Oh..

Comment: It does, when you call `renderer.render()`. See this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48662643/4045502)