# Raycast not hitting objects that have been moved from their initial default position

Tags: typescript, three.js

I am having an issue where I am trying to use a raycast to find objects under the mouse. But I cannot detect any objects that are not placed at (0, 0, 0). If I move the object anywhere else it is no longer found by the raycast.

Here's my custom class for the object I am trying to detect:

```
export default class CameraPole extends Group {
    public pole: Mesh;
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.name = 'CameraPole';

        this.pole = new Mesh(
            new CylinderGeometry(.25, .25, 5, 32),
            new MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xffffff})
        );

        // if I do not set the position here, the object is found just fine
        this.position.set(-34, 5, 17.8);

        this.add(this.pole);
    }
}
```

I construct and add it to the scene like so:

```
const cameraPole = new CameraPole();
scene.add(cameraPole);
```

Here is my mousemove event where the raycast is done:

```
document.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  const ray = new Raycaster();
  ray.setFromCamera({
    x: (e.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1,
    y: (e.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 - 1
  }, camera);
  console.log(ray.intersectObject(cameraPole, true));
});
```

Edit: I tried setting the position to (0,0,0) like this `this.position.set(0, 0, 0);` to maybe see if it's just the `.set` function that breaks it. But no, it still does get detected by the raycast with this.

So after that I figured maybe the object is moving but the collission box is still in place. But no, when I set the position to `this.position.set(-34, 5, 17.8);` it is not getting detected when I mouse over the origin point where it would be if it were at (0,0,0).

Edit 2: I have tried using `updateMatrix` and `updateMatrixWorld`, neither work in any combination.

```
this.position.set(-34, 5, 17.8);

this.updateMatrixWorld();
this.updateMatrix();
this.pole.updateMatrixWorld();
this.pole.updateMatrix();
```

Comment: Is your pole childen to another object, as it seems to be extending the Group class ? If yes, try `ray.intersectObjects(yourParentObject.children) and see how it goes

Comment: @Hesha No, it is not a child of anything else other than the actual scene. It's only an extension of group because I plan to add more meshes to it later.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be fixed by calling the method `this.pole.updateMatrixWorld()` after translating?

See the first answer to this thread:
[Raycasting after dynamically changing Mesh in Three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48662643/raycasting-after-dynamically-changing-mesh-in-three-js)

Comment: Forgot to mention I've tried that. Question edited.

Comment: ah good. That certainly doesn't make more sense. What about for a test raycasting cameraPole.pole? Does it find anything then?

Comment: It does not. I tried using `cameraPole.pole`, as well as defining the mesh outside the group class entirely and just putting it in the scene alone. Still nothing.

Comment: That is super weird.. I read your other post on the same subject. Someone pointed out that you are calculating the mouse position incorrect. I didn't notice, but he had a good point. Does that really not help? Because the way the y coordinates work on the screen does matter. your Y should be: `y: -(e.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1`

Comment: Nope, it really doesn't work when I do that. I know that sounds event weirder but yeah. Even the objects placed at (0,0,0) that I am able to find are not being found anymore when I do that.

Comment: That's rough.. Try to break the problem down to its smallest factor. For example; if you test only an empty scene with a box mesh in the center and try to raycast it with the 'correct' mouse y. That should definitely work. 

Then put the box inside a standard group and try again. Then put it in your custom group and try again.

Comment: I got another idea.. Is your renderElement the same size of the window? The way the screen coordinates of the mouse are calculated suggests so, but if it isn't that could be a problem..

Comment: Yes, the renderer fills the viewport.